# Align TextView with the progress of progressbar

Tags: android, layout, textview

How can I align a `TextView` with the progress of a horizontal `ProgressBar`. I want to put a `TextView` right above the progress position of the `ProgressBar`. The progress might be changed. Also, I want the `TextView` to be kept in one line, although the text length might be changed.

Comment: look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574271/create-custom-seekbar-in-android)

Comment: Thank U for reply. It is definitely looks like a `SeekBar` without considering the space between the `TextView` and `ProgressBar`. Maybe, I should have a try.

Comment: I think it is really a trouble to display all the text and keep it in one line if my text in `TextView` is much longer than a thumb image of a `SeekBar`.

Comment: i do not have exact requirement so i just posted a link which may helps you.describe requirement in detail.thanx

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147300/6478047

Answer (score 0):

In the parent layout which contains your TextView and Progress bar set the gravity to center so that it will keep both of them center alligned.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hiee"/>


   <ProgressBar
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But your code is keeping the `TextView` alligned with `ProgressBar`, which is not what I expected. I want the `TextView` to be alligned with the progress of the `ProgressBar`, but not the `ProgressBar` itself.

Comment: In that case, as you dynamically set your progress try adding those numbers as margin to your TextView in the direction of your progress. You will certainly have to keep trying on this to get the desired output.

Comment: Yes! I was trying to set different margins. However, as the `android:layout_width` of the `TextView` was set to be `wrap_content`, I could not find a method of getting the width of this `TextView`. `WRAP_CONTENT` is -2.

Comment: Here's a link for this I guess, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021764/in-android-how-to-get-the-width-of-the-textview-which-is-set-to-wrap-content

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the x position of thumb from progressBar  and apply it to textview

```
 var xPosition=  (((seekBar.right - seekBar.left) / seekBar.max) * seekBar.progress ) + seekBar.left

 progressTextView.translationX = xPosition.toFloat() - (progressTextView.width/2)
```