# showing progress below progressbar in a textview

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I am working on widget in which there is a progressbar and a textview below progressbar. This textview shows the current progress. But the position of textview changes according to value of progress in progressbar.Like in this image. Can anyone help me out in this Or guide me in the right direction. I would like to mention that the OS i am working on is 2.3 (10)
Thanks

[image]

Comment: for future readers https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147300/6478047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically apply X coordinates based on the progress with a 0 length animation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html

Comment: thanks for the answer but This view property animator was added in API 12. I am working on API 10.

Comment: You can still use animations. Or you can use margins.